# background default image if ng-style image loaded is invalid url

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I am adding background images to my div like this

```
ng-style="{'background-image' : 'url('+ myvariable.for.image +')'}">
```

where myvariable.for.image is a url like /examplesite/image/id

This works fine with one exception, if the image is not there it just doesnt do anything and my background looks too bla...If the image doesnt exist I want to be able to replace it with a default image.

But I cant seem to figure out how

Comment: When the image doesn't exist does the variable still contain a path or is the value undefined / null?

Comment: it still has the path if the image doesnt exists

Answer (score 9):

Instead of `ngStyle` I'd use a custom directive for this.  Such as the following.  This checks to see if an attribute is provided, if so it attempts to load that image.  If it loads an image then we set the background image to it, otherwise we use a default image.

```
myApp.directive('bgImage', function () {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {

            attr.$observe('bgImage', function() {           
              if (!attr.bgImage) {
                 // No attribute specified, so use default
                 element.css("background-image","url("+scope.defaultImage+")");
              } else {
                 var image = new Image();  
                 image.src = attr.bgImage;
                 image.onload = function() { 
                    //Image loaded- set the background image to it
                    element.css("background-image","url("+attr.bgImage+")");
                 };
                 image.onerror = function() {
                    //Image failed to load- use default
                    element.css("background-image","url("+scope.defaultImage+")");
                 };
             }
         });
      }
    };
});
```

Used like this:

```
 <div bg-image="{{person.src}}">
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J3W2A/13/)

Comment: Try the updated version I just added- the previous one had a timing issue

Comment: thank you for response. I tried that. for some reason it always go to this part of code if (!attr.bgImage) {
                console.log("no attribute at all");
                element.css("background-image","url("+scope.defaultImage+")");
            }   not sure why ...

Comment: I updated the directive to watch for changes to the attribute, in case your variable didn't have an image loaded in it when the directive first links.  See if that works for you.  If not, could you post the element that uses the directive?

Comment: Try encapsulating the css update procedure into a $timeout block (no delay needed). That worked for me in ionic.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div err-bg-src='{{default_business_logo_wd}}' ng-style="{'background-image' : 'url('+ifNull(place.logo_wd,default_business_logo_wd)+')'}" id="perfilEstablecimiento-container10" class="place-header">
    <div id="perfilEstablecimiento-container13" class="place-title-container">
        <h4 id="perfilEstablecimiento-heading1" class="place-title">{{place.name}}</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using a $timeout inside that custom directive worked for me.

```
.directive
(
    'errBgSrc',
    function($timeout)
    {
        return {
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) 
            {
                $timeout
                (
                    function()
                    {
                        if(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(attrs.id)).backgroundImage=='none'||window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(attrs.id)).backgroundImage==null)
                        {
                            document.getElementById(attrs.id).style.backgroundImage='url('+attrs.errBgSrc+')';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var image = new Image();
                            var style=window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(attrs.id)).backgroundImage;
                            var url=style.slice(5,style.length-2);
                            image.src = url;

                            image.onerror = function()
                            {
                                document.getElementById(attrs.id).style.backgroundImage='url('+attrs.errBgSrc+')';
                            };
                        }
                    },
                    500
                );

            }
        }
    }
)
```