# Default background image with css and angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am creating a list using ng-repeat, and the image for list item is called based on list property, and image name is same as that property.

Here is the my JSON format on which I am using ng-repeat.

```
[{
   header:"Name",
   image:"imgname"
}]
```

I am using ng-style to load dynamic background image.

```
<div ng-style="{'background-image':'url(../img/'+list.image+'.png)'"></div>
```

The problem with this is it is showing blank if the image is not available. and I want to show a default image if it doesn't found any image.

***I cant use img tag***

Comment: This could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056699/background-default-image-if-ng-style-image-loaded-is-invalid-url

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan, Thank you, got the answer